# How To Scroll a TStringGrid dynamically?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, tstringgrid

I am working in the Borland C++Builder IDE, using VCL controls. I am trying to get a TStringGrid component to scroll down to a row and highlight that row, based on user input in a different form. I have the highlight portion done, but I can't figure out how to scroll the grid down to the correct row. Anyone here know?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set the `TopRow` property.

Comment: I dont know if  I'm happy This worked, or upset I spent so much time trying to figure out something this simple. Either way, Thaks a ton!